# X windows on ARM based platform

Tags: arm, framebuffer

I am using arm based reference platform. In that I have VGA display. If I want to develop a image viewer software for that platform, do I need to learn about X windows programming? Kindly provide your valuable inputs. Does this involved frame buffer concepts?
rgds,
yaj

Answer (score 0):

you can use directfb as lib for framebuffer access (directfb.org) it will be simply enough for  this task and performance will be greater than for x server+window manager (but you must think about graphical acceleration, on my board only xaa (for specific version x.org) driver is available)